# DirectLine API: Define a new ChannelId

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm implementing a new channel for my bot's front end using the botframework-directlinejs NodeJS SDK. This channel will provide some custom back-channel functionality; however, my bot needs to know that the conversation it is communicating with is via this channel before it can construct an activity to use it.

From what I can gather from the ['Activity' object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#activity-object) in the API, the `channelId` field should be set by the channel.

However,

```
myChannel.postActivity({
    type: 'message',
    text: 'hi',
    from: {
        id: "Node test user",
    },
    channelId: 'myChannel'
}).subscribe(
    id => console.log("Posted activity, assigned ID ", id),
    error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
);
```

indeed sends the message 'hi' to my bot, but the channelId comes out as 'directline'.

Performing this same operation in Fiddler as a post to `https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/<conversationID>/activities` has the same response.

My suspicion is that the 'channelId' property of the Activity object is read-only, and that the API adds this value.

Is it possible to set a custom id of the channel?

Comment: I'd also accept a way to programmatically identify the 'site name' of the DirectLine instance; this'd provide a suitable hack to get around this

Comment: Yeah, that bugs me too! They provide a property, but bot receive `directline`. I have multiple directline instances for different purposes. I identify each of them using `user` property. But thats not the best way. I will keep an eye here, if there is a proper resolution.

Comment: As MasterChief mentioned, we can pass custom channel info via `user` property or `from` field of an activity, like this `from: { id: 'Node test user', channelID: "myChannel" }`. And then we can get it from `activity.From.Properties["channelID"]` in bot application.

Comment: I'm using TypeScript, so while I could do that, the User typings disagrees with it. True I could force it like `from: { ... } as User`, but I'd prefer a more agreeable solution if I can find one.
It has occurred to me to use the `channelData` object in both directions (especially since it has type `any`).

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to set a custom channel id.  There is a corresponding connector service for each channel type.  If you're using Direct Line, the channelId should be **directline**.

You can send custom information through channel data though:

```
BotChat.App({
  botConnection: Object.assign({}, dl, {
     postActivity: activity => {
     var newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity, { channelData: { "MyKey": "MyValue" } });
     return dl.postActivity(newActivity);
    }
  }),
  bot: bot,
  user: user,
  resize: 'detect',
}, document.getElementById('bot'));
```